# C# LINQ build expression with anonymous type

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, expression

I have code which builds list only with one property "Name".
How to modify the code so it can build list with two properties "Name" and "Test_Result"
I know that anonymous type can be used to perform this, but how to put them to dynamic expression?
here is my code:

```
string item = "Name";
string item2 = "Test_Result";
Type studentType = typeof(Student);

ParameterExpression itemParam = Expression.Parameter(studentType, item);
MemberInfo itemProperty = studentType.GetProperty(item);

MemberExpression valueInItemField = 
    Expression.MakeMemberAccess(itemParam, itemProperty);

Expression<Func<Student, string>> selectExpression =
    Expression<Func<Student, string>>
        .Lambda<Func<Student, string>>(valueInItemField, itemParam);

IEnumerable<string> currentItemFields = 
    DeserializedStudents.Select(selectExpression.Compile());
```

Comment: Re your most recent repeat of the same; please clarify what is still unclear after the answers here and on your earlier question. If you tell us what is unclear, we can probably clarify.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I'm assuming that the "Name" and "Test_Result" here are flexible and cannot be hard-coded.

Anonymous types are fully defined regular classes; the only interesting thing about them is that the *compiler* provides the details instead of you.

I would suggest that the way to handle this scenario would be to use `Tuple.Create` to create an `IEnumerable<Tuple<string,string>>` and refer to them as `Item1`, `Item2` (the names from `Tuple<,>`. The other option would be to use something like `ExpandoObject`, and then use either the `IDictionary<string,object>` API, or the `dynamic` API, to get the values back out.

For example:

```
string item1 = "Name";
string item2 = "Test_Result";
Type studentType = typeof(Student);

var itemParam = Expression.Parameter(studentType, "x");
var member1 = Expression.PropertyOrField(itemParam, item1);
var member2 = Expression.PropertyOrField(itemParam, item2);
var selector = Expression.Call(typeof(Tuple), "Create",
    new[] { member1.Type, member2.Type }, member1, member2);
var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<Student, Tuple<string,string>>>(
    selector, itemParam);

var currentItemFields = students.Select(lambda.Compile());
```

---

Here's the same projecting into a custom type with members `name` and `result`:

```
class ProjectedData
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string result { get; set; }
}

...

string item1 = "Name";
string item2 = "Test_Result";
Type studentType = typeof(Student);

var itemParam = Expression.Parameter(studentType, "x");
var member1 = Expression.PropertyOrField(itemParam, item1);
var member2 = Expression.PropertyOrField(itemParam, item2);
var selector = Expression.MemberInit(Expression.New(typeof(ProjectedData)),
    Expression.Bind(typeof(ProjectedData).GetMember("name").Single(), member1),
    Expression.Bind(typeof(ProjectedData).GetMember("result").Single(), member2)
);
var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<Student, ProjectedData>>(
    selector, itemParam);

var currentItemFields = students.Select(lambda.Compile());
```

---

Or for the approach using a dictionary:

```
string[] fields = {"Name", "Test_Result"};
Type studentType = typeof(Student);

var itemParam = Expression.Parameter(studentType, "x");

var addMethod = typeof(Dictionary<string, object>).GetMethod(
    "Add", new[] { typeof(string), typeof(object) });
var selector = Expression.ListInit(
        Expression.New(typeof(Dictionary<string,object>)),
        fields.Select(field => Expression.ElementInit(addMethod,
            Expression.Constant(field),
            Expression.Convert(
                Expression.PropertyOrField(itemParam, field),
                typeof(object)
            )
        )));
var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<Student, Dictionary<string,object>>>(
    selector, itemParam);

var currentItemFields = students.Select(lambda.Compile());
```

Comment: i mean i would like to change

var students = DeserializedStudents.Select(cust => new { name = cust.Name, result = cust.Test_Result });

to dynamic expression

Comment: @Yarik you would have to define your own type is the point; if you are happy to define some type somewhere with members `name` and `result`, then fine: just create a `class`. I can add an example of that in a moment (done).

Comment: Could you tell me please one more thing?
What should I do if don't know how many items i will need to select.
I mean one time it can be two items, next time it can be four items and so on. Should i create some list with that items or what?

Comment: @Yarik personally I would populate a dictionary with the values. Do you want an example?

Comment: @Yarik added at the bottom

Comment: hi Mark! what if I need almost the same but want the result as list of anonymous types? For example how I can simulate situation like this Expression<Func<Student, object>> exp = s => new { Name = s.Name, Result= s.Test_Result }; in order to use it late somewhere like this students.Select(exp).ToList();

Comment: @mr-pumpkin did you find the answer to your problem? I'm now having something similar, but just the s.Name and s.Test_Result are not hard coded and they get from an input during runtime as a list of string