# Build GroupBy expression tree with multiple fields

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, expression-trees

To dynamically generate a GroupBy expression, I am trying to build a Linq expression tree. The fields to group by are dynamic and can differ in number.

I use this code:

```
string[] fields = {"Name", "Test_Result"};
Type studentType = typeof(Student);

var itemParam = Expression.Parameter(studentType, "x");

var addMethod = typeof(Dictionary<string, object>).GetMethod(
    "Add", new[] { typeof(string), typeof(object) });
var selector = Expression.ListInit(
        Expression.New(typeof(Dictionary<string,object>)),
        fields.Select(field => Expression.ElementInit(addMethod,
            Expression.Constant(field),
            Expression.Convert(
                Expression.PropertyOrField(itemParam, field),
                typeof(object)
            )
        )));
var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<Student, Dictionary<string,object>>>(
    selector, itemParam);
```

The code is copied from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14214313/2366136) (Thanks Mark Gravel!).

It finalizes with ...

```
var currentItemFields = students.Select(lambda.Compile());
```

... of which I expected that I could change it to ...

```
var currentItemFields = students.GroupBy(lambda.Compile());
```

I assumed that the lambda expression is nothing more than ...

```
var currentItemFields = students.GroupBy(o => new { o.Name, o.Test_Result });
```

... but unfortunally that seems not to be the case. The GroupBy with a dynamic lambda does not give any exceptions, it just doesn't group anything and returns all elements.

What am I doing wrong here? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you print out the generated expression, before compiling it, what does it look like?

Comment: @Servy Like this: {x => new Dictionary`2() {Void Add(System.String, System.Object)("Shift", Convert(x.Shift)), Void Add(System.String, System.Object)("Section", Convert(x.Section))}}

Comment: So shouldn't it be obvious from what you see there that the end result is a dictionary, and you know that grouping on a dictionary will do comparisons based on the dictionary's reference, not its contents, making the results clear.

Comment: If you compile those lambda's, you are doomed to rely on client side evaluation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That lambda expression builds a dictionary of grouping fields.
`Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` does not implement `Equals()` and `GetHashCode()`, so it groups them by reference equality.
Since you always return a new dictionary, each item gets its own group.

You need to change it to create a type that correctly implements `Equals()` and `GetHashCode()` for value equality.
Ordinarily, you would have the compiler generate an anonymous type.  However, you can't do that here since you don't know the type signature at compile-time.
Instead, you can construct a `Tuple<...>`:

```
Expression.New(
    Type.GetType("System.Tuple`" + fields.Length)
        .MakeGenericType(fields.Select(studentType.GetProperty), 
    fields.Select(f => Expression.PropertyOrField(itemParam, f))
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your useful answer, it helped me to find a solution, as I posted in a separate answer. Maybe you like to know that the sample code you wrote misses a parenthesis and gives a conversion error.

Answer (score 7):

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9001249/2366136) shows a expression function which can be used for both Select and GroupBy. Hope it helps others!

```
public Expression<Func<TItem, object>> GroupByExpression<TItem>(string[] propertyNames)
{
    var properties = propertyNames.Select(name => typeof(TItem).GetProperty(name)).ToArray();
    var propertyTypes = properties.Select(p => p.PropertyType).ToArray();
    var tupleTypeDefinition = typeof(Tuple).Assembly.GetType("System.Tuple`" + properties.Length);
    var tupleType = tupleTypeDefinition.MakeGenericType(propertyTypes);
    var constructor = tupleType.GetConstructor(propertyTypes);
    var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TItem), "item");
    var body = Expression.New(constructor, properties.Select(p => Expression.Property(param, p)));
    var expr = Expression.Lambda<Func<TItem, object>>(body, param);
    return expr;
}
```

To be called like this:

```
var lambda = GroupByExpression<Student>(fields);
var currentItemFields = students.GroupBy(lambda.Compile());
```

Comment: How can I identify the keys for further selection after group by? Thanks.

Comment: I haven't tried this, but why should the fluent way not work?
students.GroupBy(lambda1.Compile()).Select(lambda2.Compile());
The expression function can work for both GroupBy and [Select](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9000753/how-can-i-create-a-dynamic-multi-property-select-on-an-ienumerablet-at-runtime/9001249#9001249).

Comment: This is a nice solution that I've used. I think the drawback is that it fails on line 5 (tupleTypeDefinition) if you have more than 8 propertyNames, although that was not needed in my case. I think for more than 8 elements in a tuple, the last element is a new tuple definition of the remaining elements. I assume nested like that to inf. so one could probably amend the code slightly to support this definition.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.tuple-8?view=netcore-3.0

Comment: Cannot be translated by entity framework...