# multiple groupby in linq C# by List of properties

Tags: c#, linq

I have 
List GroupProperyKeys
and in my code I'm getting the Properties info

```
 List<PropertyInfo> propertiesKeys = new List<PropertyInfo>();
 foreach (string key in this.GroupProperyKeys)
 {
    PropertyInfo p = typeof(T).GetProperty(key);
    if (p != null)
      propertiesKeys.Add(p);
 }
```

now I want to group my list by the given properties.
In case I have one property to group by it's look like this

```
PropertyInfo keyProperty = typeof(T).GetProperty(this.GroupProperyKey);
if (keyProperty != null)
{
   var group = m_list.GroupBy(x => keyProperty.GetValue(x));
}
```

Is it possible to group by list of properties?

Thank you in advanced

Comment: Ok but I want it to be something like foreach p in properties { groupby}

Comment: I can't see the option .ThenBy

Comment: Can you please write me code sample of what you mean. Because I don't understand how do you save it in var group

Comment: ThenBy is for order not for group

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6935264/group-by-with-multiple-columns-using-lambda

Comment: I know how to group by multiple columns, the question is how to group by dynamically with properties list?

Comment: Ok I found the answer [here][1]
Thank you all


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21143179/build-groupby-expression-tree-with-multiple-fields